# Mapping an existing local neo4j database to a neo4j docker container

Tags: docker, neo4j, docker-compose, dockerfile

EDIT: I'm running on OSX.

So I am having troubles mapping an existing local database to my newly created docker container and am struggling to find the answer via google.

Here is my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '2'
services:
  neo4j:
    image: neo4j
    ports:
     - "7474:7474"
    volumes:
      - /Users/**/Documents/Neo4j/**.graphdb:/data
    environment:
       NEO4J_AUTH: neo4j/**
```

I have double checked

```
volumes:
      - /Users/**/Documents/Neo4j/**.graphdb:/data
```

is pointing at the correct directory (stars are hiding personal details). Using this same URL in the neo4j desktop app works fine.

Any help would be great,

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry I forget to say, I'm running on OSX, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case anyone else runs into this problem, I contacted the creators of the neo4j container. Here is the thread that led to a solution: [Git hub](https://github.com/neo4j/docker-neo4j/issues/66).

My issue was miss understanding how the data volume maps to my local neo4j database.